# Run KMeans with fixed seed

Tags: apache-spark, k-means, apache-spark-mllib

I want to run the KMeans algorithm of MLLIB (Apache Spark), but with reproducible results.

Is it possible to run KMeans of MLLIB (Apache Spark) with fixed seed? How?

Thanks and regards,

Answer (score 0):

As of Spark 1.2, it appears that this is not possible. It generates a seed internally.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Sean. I was under the same impression.

Answer (score 0):

Set seed for KMeans is availble in Spark MLLib since version 1.4.0 
See doc library [here](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.mllib.clustering.KMeans)